# Deleting duplicate records in PostgreSQL database from Multiple tables (Having Foreign Key references)

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, record

We have a Postgres database in our environment. Due to some human mistake the application inserted duplicated records in multiple tables which are having foreign key relations. If it is for few tables we can remove the duplicates but we have many tables few are larger in size. Is there any way / script that can identify all the parent -child relations and to remove the duplicate entries from the whole database.

We have tried to restore the database schema first and then the latest data only using pg_restore but faced many errors

Comment: if you now all ids form the parent, you write a SELECT where you join all tables and reduce the resultset to the know parents. if you have foreiogn keys with delete all would delete all child with the parents if not you will have to search how to delete multiple tables, where the first mentioned select comes in handy

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you have `FOREIGN KEY` constraints, ensure that `ON DELETE` they `CASCADE`, and you should be able to easily `DELETE` all the records you need.